# Как перемешать список, чтобы ни один из элементов не остался на прежнем месте?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть список, нужно перемешать его элементы случайным образом, причем так, чтобы ни один из элементов не остался на прежнем месте.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А какие-то ограничения есть? Ну в смысле все элементы списка разные, например, или возможны повторы?

Comment: Зря минусуете - хороший практический вопрос по алгоритмам

Comment: @Kromster
это не сайт по заданиям, а для тех кто пытался что-то сделать, но пока не получется

Comment: @СергейКох это и не задание, а вопрос про то, *каким* алгоритмом можно выполнить.

Comment: @Kromster https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279895/shuffle-list-ensuring-that-no-item-remains-in-same-position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Простая реализация алгоритма Саттоло на языке Python
>
> ```
> from random import randrange
>
> def sattoloCycle(items):
>     i = len(items)
>     while i > 1:
>         i = i - 1
>         j = randrange(i)  # 0 <= j <= i-1
>         items[j], items[i] = items[i], items[j]
>     return
> ```

Взято с Вики - [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тасование_Фишера_—_Йетса#Алгоритм_Саттоло](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE) (там же я пояснения почему это работает)

Answer (score -1):

```
random_list = ['first_el','second_el','third_el']


print(set(random_list))
Попробуй сделать так.
или так 
import random
print(random.choice(random_list))
```

Comment: А в чем здесь случайность?

Comment: А где гарантия, чтобы "ни один из элементов не остался на прежнем месте"?